# The correct way to exit a thread in Qt with finished signal and make clean_up

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, qt

I have a application that hast many threads.I want to exit the threads when I close my main application and call thread destructors to make necesseary clean up.

```
 Class Thread :public QThread{

 Thread(); 

  run(){

     while(1){

       //do work 
     } 

  }

 ~Thread(){

  //want to make clean up

     }
 }; 


 Class my_app :public QCoreapplication{

 my_app(){

 Thread th1;

 connect(&th1,SIGNAL(finished()),&th1,deleteLater());
 connect(&th1,SIGNAL(finished()),&th1,quit());


 }

 };




 //And my th1 thread runs in while.So I know that is the problem it runs on while and never emits the finished signal

 //How can be achievable?
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that?  Beware of premature stoptimization.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Do not subclass QThread](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/)
2. in worker loop provide some thread safe flag which will indicate that worker should end its job.
3. Before terminate application you should call [QThread::wait](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html#wait) to ensure that thread will end gracefully before application is terminated.

Comment: What if it does not matter about 'graceful termination'?  If the thread is already stuck on a blocking call, waiting for it to terminate could take forever, resulting in an app that will not close and is unresponsive.

Comment: worker can hold some important resources: files, network connections and other stuff. Ending thread in proper way will save you from errors like corrupted files (lost data), proper connection ending and so on. Also many testing tools will not report false alerts.

Comment: 'worker can hold some important resources' - 'can'.  If you can design so that they do not, it is not necessary to 'gracefully terminate' the threads:)  Non-graceful termination of the threads, ie. when the OS stops them on process termiantion, does have an important advantage - it always works, no matter what the state of the thread, even if it is running on another core.

Comment: Yes system will cleanup most of the stuff but it can't do everything, for example send to server some closing sequence, or send to external device shutdown instructions. Even if you do not have this spatial cases it is better to do full cleanup in application so some tools (like valgrind) could provide useful reports without false positives.

Answer (score 1):

In your run function the while loop will cause your thread to never stop unless you manage thread termination by your self like:

```
Class Thread :public QThread{

Thread(); 

protected:

   void run()
   {

      while(1)
      {
          if(this->finishThread==true)
              return;
      } 

   }

private:

  bool finishThread;
}
```

You are better to derive your class from QObject and use moveToThread. You can do this in the constructor of your class:

```
th = new QThread();

this->setParent(0);
this->moveToThread(th);
clientSocket.moveToThread(th);

QObject::connect(th,SIGNAL(started()),this,SLOT(OnStarted()));
QObject::connect(th,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(OnFinished()));

th->start();
```

Your initialization and termination tasks should be done in OnStarted() and OnFinished() slots respectively.

In the destructor of your class add this:

```
th->quit();
th->wait();
```

Comment: 'th->wait();' - and if the thread is already blocked somewhere?

Comment: @MartinJames Easy: Provide a non-zero argument to `th->wait()`: `th->quit(); th->wait(500); if (!th->isFinished()) th->terminate();`